# Html canvas - rotate individual shapes on center axis

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As you can see in the demo the L shape is getting cropped off the top of the screen and should be rotated 180 degrees and flush with the top left corner. I noticed two things that don't work as expected, the first is when I change `ctx.translate(x, y)` to `ctx.moveTo(x, y)` and increase the shape position to `100, 100` it moves more than 100px with translate, where as moveTo seems accurate. The second is that using a negative translate after `ctx.stroke()` has no affect on the shapes position.

```js
var shape = {};

function draw(shape) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();

    var x = shape.position.x + 0.5;
    var y = shape.position.y + 0.5;
    ctx.translate(x, y);

    ctx.translate(shape.width * shape.scale/2, shape.height * shape.scale/2);
    ctx.rotate(shape.orientation * Math.PI/180);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < shape.points.length; i++) {
      x = shape.points[i].x * shape.scale + shape.position.x + 0.5;
      y =  shape.points[i].y * shape.scale + shape.position.y + 0.5;
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.translate(-shape.width * shape.scale/2, -shape.height * shape.scale/2);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

// L Shape
shape.points = [];
shape.points.push({ x:0, y:0 });
shape.points.push({ x:0, y:3 });
shape.points.push({ x:2, y:3 });
shape.points.push({ x:2, y:2 });
shape.points.push({ x:1, y:2 });
shape.points.push({ x:1, y:0 });
shape.points.push({ x:0, y:0 });

shape.position = {x: 0, y: 0};
shape.scale = 30;
shape.width = 3;
shape.height = 2;
shape.orientation = 180;
draw(shape);
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: #272B34; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="600"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do 2D tranforms is via the setTransform function which takes 6 numbers, 2 vectors representing the direction and scale of the X and y axis, and one coordinate representing the new origin.

Unlike the other transform functions which are dependent of the current state setTransform is not effected by any transform done before it is called.

To set the transform for a matrix that has a square aspect (x and y scale are the same) and that the y axis is at 90 deg to the x ( no skewing) and a rotation is as follows

```
// x,y the position of the orign
function setMatrix(x,y,scale,rotate){ 
    var xAx = Math.cos(rotate) * scale;  // the x axis x
    var xAy = Math.sin(rotate) * scale;  // the x axis y
    ctx.setTransform(xAx, xAy, -xAy, xAx, x, y);
}

//use
setMatrix(100,100,20,Math.PI / 4);
ctx.strokeRect(-2,-2,4,4); // draw a square centered at 100,100 
                           // scaled 20 times
                           // and rotate clockwise 45 deg
```

### Update

In response to the questions in the comments.

#### Why sin and cos?

> Can you also explain why you used cos and sin for the axis?

I use `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` to calculate the X axis and thus the Y axis as well (because y is at 90 deg to x) because it is slightly quicker than adding the rotation as a separate transform.

When you use any of the transform functions apart from `setTransform` you are doing a matrix multiplication. The next snippet is the JS equivalent minimum calculations done when using `ctx.rotate`, `ctx.scale`, `ctx.translate`, or `ctx.transform`

```
// mA represent the 2D context current transform
mA = [1,0,0,1,0,0];  // default transform
// mB represents the transform to apply
mB = [0,1,-1,0,0,0];  // Rotate 90 degree clockwise
// m is the resulting matrix
m[0] = mA[0] * mB[0] + mA[2] * mB[1];
m[1] = mA[1] * mB[0] + mA[3] * mB[1];
m[2] = mA[0] * mB[2] + mA[2] * mB[3];
m[3] = mA[1] * mB[2] + mA[3] * mB[3];
m[4] = mA[0] * mB[0] + mA[2] * mB[1] + mA[4];
m[5] = mA[1] * mB[0] + mA[3] * mB[1] + mA[5];
```

As you can see there are 12 multiplications and 6 additions plus the need for memory to hold the intermediate values and if the call was to `ctx.rotation` the sin and cos of the angle would also be done. This is all done in native code in the JavaScript engine so is quicker than doing in JS, but side stepping the matrix multiplication by calculating the axis in JavaScript results in less work. Using `setTransform` simply replaces the current matrix and does not require a matrix multiplication  to be performed.

The alternative to the answer's `setMatrix` function can be

```
function setMatrix(x,y,scale,rotate){ 
    ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale, x, y); // set current matrix
    ctx.rotate(rotate);  // multiply current matrix with rotation matrix
}
```

which does the same and does look cleaner, though is slower and when you want to do things like games where performance is very important often called functions should be as quick as possible.

#### To use the `setMatrix` function

> So how would I use this for custom shapes like the L in my demo?

Replacing your draw function. BTW you should be getting the context outside any draw function.

```
// assumes ctx is the 2D context in scope for this function.
function draw(shape) { 
    var i = 0;
    setMatrix(shape.position.x, shape.position.y, shape.scale, shape.orientation); // orientation is in radians
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(shape.points[i].x, shape.points[i++].y)
    while (i < shape.points.length) {
      ctx.lineTo(shape.points[i].x, shape.points[i++].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath(); // draw line from end to start
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

In your code you have the line stored such that its origin (0,0) is at the top left. When defining shapes you should define it in terms of its local coordinates. This will define the point of rotation and scaling and represents the coordinate that will be at the transforms origin (position x,y).

Thus you should define your shape at its origin

```
function createShape(originX, originY, points){
    var i;
    const shape = [];
    for(i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
        shape.push({
            x : points[i][0] - originX,
            y : points[i][1] - originY,
        });
    }
    return shape;
}
const shape = {};
shape.points = createShape(
     1,1.5,  // the local origin relative to the coords on next line
     [[0,0],[0,3],[2,3],[2,2],[1,2],[1,0]]  // shape coords
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67 for all the help so far! So how would I use this for custom shapes like the L in my demo? Can you also explain why you used cos and sin for the axis?

Comment: @PaulMason I have updated the answer to answer your additional questions.

Comment: Hey @Blindman67 I've had a go, and it's almost there, really appreciate the help so far! I made a Codepen to point out 1 last thing, see how its out of proportion, the part sticking out should be the same width as the stem: https://codepen.io/paulmason/pen/Qvroxa?editors=0010

Comment: @PaulMason That is because you are using stroke, the line `ctx.lineTo` defines the center of the line so you have half the line width on each side of that line. If you replace `ctx.stroke()` with `ctx.fill()` @ (line 38) and `ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFF"` with `ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF"` (line 28) you will get the correct shape

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67 you've been super helpful! I also found this works `ctx.lineWidth = .1;`